# How do I create an XAML file from an object graph in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

This is the code I use in .NET, but System.XAML doesn't exist in Silverlight.

```
    public static string CreateXaml(object source)
    {
        var reader = new XamlObjectReader(source);
        var xamlString = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new XamlXmlWriter(xamlString, reader.SchemaContext);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteNode(reader);
        }
        writer.Close();
        return xamlString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Your code example would be more compact using the following syntax.
string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(source);

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am building unit tests. Being able to represent test data as XAML is really useful because it can build objects that cannot be represented as data contract xml or json due to things like constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well XamlWriter doesn't exist in Silverlight.

You may want to look at this blog post about creating one [David Poll's XamlWriter](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/)

the SilverlightContrib project has one as well [SilverlightContrib](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/49151?projectName=silverlightcontrib#602856)